# Inverse Fourier Transform involving Bessel function

Tags: fourier-transform, closed-form, bessel-functions

Lately, I have come accross a difficult inverse Fourier transform computation (or at least for me) and I have no idea how to start or if there is any tricks to use. Let us define the functions of interest as:

\begin{equation*}
\tilde{Z}_n(u, v) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Z_n(x,y) e^{-i (xu+yv)} dx dy
\end{equation*}

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307728/recurrence-relation-involving-derivative), I demonstrated that:
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{Z}_n(u, v) = \tilde{Z}_0\frac{\lambda_1^n + \lambda_2^n}{2} - \tilde{Z}_0\frac{iv}{\sqrt{u^2 - 1}}\frac{\lambda_1^n - \lambda_2^n}{2}
\end{equation*}
where $\tilde{Z}_0$ is the Fourier transform of $Z_0(x, y) = 2\pi J_0\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)e^{id}$ and $\lambda_{1, 2}$ are defined as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\lambda_1 = u - \sqrt{u^2 - 1}, \\
\lambda_2 = u + \sqrt{u^2 - 1}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Using [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we can write:
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{Z}_n(u, v) = \tilde{Z}_0\sum_{k=0}^{n} \begin{pmatrix}
n\\
k
\end{pmatrix}
u^{n-k}\left(u^2 - 1\right)^\frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}+\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}\frac{iv}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\right)
\end{equation*}

Using the computation done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005075/2d-fourier-of-bessel?rq=1), we have:
\begin{equation}
\tilde{Z}_0(u, v) = 2\pi e^{id} \delta(\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}-1), \\
\end{equation}

Is there any way to inverse the transformation and get back $Z_n(x, y)$? Considering the origin of the problem, I guess that Bessel functions should be involved.

I found the solution of my initial problem via another method than the inverse Fourier transform (see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307728/recurrence-relation-involving-derivative/4321066#4321066) for the full answer), the solution being:
\begin{align*}
Z_{\pm n} = \left(\frac{x\pm iy}{x^2+y^2}\right)^{n}\left[r^2 J_0(r) \sum_{k=1}^{u_n}a_k^{n} \left(x^2 + y^2\right)^{k-1} + i^n r J_1(r) \sum_{k=1}^{u_{n+1}}b_k^{n} \left(x^2 + y^2\right)^{k-1}\right]
\end{align*}
where $n\geq 1$ and $u_n$ is defined as $u_n = \left(2n+(-1)^n -1\right)/4$. The two coefficients can be computed using:
\begin{equation*}
\forall k\geq 1, n\geq 2k,\quad a_k^{n} = (2i)^{n-2k}\frac{(n-k)!}{(k-1)!k!}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(n-(k+i))
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\forall k\geq 1, n\geq 2k-1,\quad b_k^{n} = (-1)^{k+1}2^{n-(2k-1)}\frac{(n-k)!}{(k-1)!(k-1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(n-(k-1+i))
\end{equation*}
If anyone wants to demonstrate this result using inverse Fourier transform, be my guest...